# Prevent list view from auto stretching

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My list view:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV_" Margin="0,60,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Column definition (set in code):

```
new ColumnDefinition[]
{
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(150) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(150) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) }
}
```

When I now load an item list where the second item (which has a width of 1*) is a long string, the list stretches itself over the bounds of the page (to the length of the text).

How can I prevent this (and display for example 'abcabcab...') while still having a list view which uses the full width of the page?

**Edit:**

Generated item template:

```
    <DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="0" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="5" Background="{Binding BackgroundBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Day}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Department}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Begin}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding End}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Allocation}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Position}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding ServiceType}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Info}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: If you want to trim your text in Second Column, If you are using DataTemplate and showing Text in TextBlock, add `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` to the properties. That should take care.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work

Comment: Can you provide your data template? Also why are you populating grid in code behind? And can you show the data points that you are trying to add?

Comment: Has the `ColumnDefinition` been  used in `ListView DataTemplate` ? Please share more code about layout.

Comment: Yes, I added the generated item template

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to add `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` setting, to solve this issue, one way is to add a Border outside of the `TextBlock`, and set the Width for `TextBlock` based on the `ActualWidth` property of Border.

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=.ActualWidth}" Text="{Binding Department}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}"/>
</Border>
```

Full XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv1" Margin="0,60,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MinWidth="0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MinWidth="0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="0" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="5" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Day}" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}"/>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=.ActualWidth}" Text="{Binding Department}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Begin}" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding End}" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Allocation}" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Position}" Foreground="{ StaticResource TextBrushLight}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: There's a dot before ActualWidth. What's it for? TemplateParent only works in control template doesn't it?

Comment: @Jessica The dot is for access the ActualWidth property correctly in XAML. About the {RelativeSource} markup extension, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension

Comment: This is wrong. First, ActualWidth is not updating, and this is by design. Second, the doc clearly says it's used inside a control template.

Comment: @Jessica Actually, in my xaml sample which has been tested, the ActualWidth is updating, the Width property can be set when have changes. For Doc, it says "Produces a ControlTemplate that is applied as the source for this binding.". I don't think this means you have to use it in a ControlTemplate

Comment: @Jessica I will double check this doc internally and update here

Comment: I don't think it's updating at all. Inject a test converter into the binding and you will see it's never called.

Comment: I have tried everything, but I couldn't get it to work, same result with or without the border...

Comment: @Jessica actually, `TemplatedParent` works in data template too, but `ActualWidth` might not work.